# TCL twapi and Excel ; excel.exe still running in the background

Tags: excel, tcl

I am using 4.1.27 (I think it also happens with 4.2.12 ) 64bit twapi to write some data to excel and It is generating excel fine. However, I see excel.exe running in TaskManager after the operation.

twapi and Excel ; excel.exe still running background. Is there anything I need to need do other than -destroy commands?

```
package require twapi 

set excelOutFile {C:\AA\1.xlsx}

set application [::twapi::comobj Excel.Application]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
$worksheet Activate
set cells [$worksheet Cells]

set range [$worksheet Range "A1"]
$range ColumnWidth [expr "20.0"]

set range [$worksheet Range "A1" "A8"]


$range NumberFormat "0.0"
set a "88501200600667"
$cells Item [expr 1] [expr 1] $a


$workbook SaveAs $excelOutFile
#$application Quit
$cells -destroy
$range -destroy
$worksheet -destroy 
$worksheets -destroy 
$workbook -destroy 
$workbooks -destroy 
$application -destroy

unset application
```

Comment: The `Quit` is commented out?

Comment: '$application Quit ' didn't make any difference.  It turned out I need a '$range -destroy' command after $range ColumnWidth [expr "20.0"]. It is now working as expected.