# Powerpoint does not close - Tcl - TWAPI

Tags: tcl, powerpoint

I have created a tcl script that is supposed to perform following activities:

1. Open ppt object
2. Add new slide
3. Paste animation (.avi) files.
4. Save the file
5. Close the ppt

Everything works fine, but at the end ppt does not close. Here is the code that I have written. Is there anything that I am missing out?

```
set job_folder "C:\\Users\\xcxc\\Desktop\\test_ui\\test" 

set num_of_modes 15

#get the directory#
set dirname [file dirname [info script]]
set template_dirname "$dirname/Report_Template.pptx"


#handle the files#

file copy -force "$dirname/Report_Template.pptx" "$job_folder/Report/Report.pptx"

#modify the PPts#
package require twapi
set ppt [::twapi::comobj PowerPoint.Application]
$ppt DisplayAlerts [expr 0]
set presents [$ppt Presentations]
$presents Open "$job_folder/Report/Report.pptx"; #Open the Presnetation
set active_presentation [$ppt ActivePresentation]; #get the cureently active presentaatin
set slides [$active_presentation Slides]; #gte the slide list
set slide_1 [$slides Item 1]; #get control on slide index 1


set object_list {}
set mode_counter 1
while {$mode_counter <= $num_of_modes} {
    set slide_num [expr {$mode_counter + 1}]
    set slide_$slide_num [$slides Add $slide_num 12]; #add one more slide into the presentation

    set slide_$slide_num\_shapes [[set slide_$slide_num] Shapes]

    set slide_$slide_num\_video_1 [[set slide_$slide_num\_shapes] AddMediaObject2 [file nativename "$job_folder/Report/Mode_$mode_counter\_Iso_Front.avi"] -1 -1 20 100 650 300]

    set slide_$slide_num\_video_2 [[set slide_$slide_num\_shapes] AddMediaObject2 [file nativename "$job_folder/Modal_Analysis/Report/Mode_$mode_counter\_Iso_Back.avi"] -1 -1 500 100 650 300]


    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_shapes"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_video_1"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_video_2"

    incr mode_counter 1
}


$active_presentation Save 

foreach object $object_list {
    puts $object
    [set $object] -destroy
}

$slides -destroy
$active_presentation -destroy 


$ppt Quit
$ppt -destroy
```

**Update - Added $presents -destroy**

```
set job_folder "C:\\Users\\xcxc\\Desktop\\test_ui\\test" 

set num_of_modes 15

#get the directory#
set dirname [file dirname [info script]]
set template_dirname "$dirname/Report_Template.pptx"


#handle the files#

file copy -force "$dirname/Report_Template.pptx" "$job_folder/Report/Report.pptx"

#modify the PPts#
package require twapi
set ppt [::twapi::comobj PowerPoint.Application]
$ppt DisplayAlerts [expr 0]
set presents [$ppt Presentations]
$presents Open "$job_folder/Report/Report.pptx"; #Open the Presnetation
set active_presentation [$ppt ActivePresentation]; #get the cureently active presentaatin
set slides [$active_presentation Slides]; #gte the slide list
set slide_1 [$slides Item 1]; #get control on slide index 1


set object_list {}
set mode_counter 1
while {$mode_counter <= $num_of_modes} {
    set slide_num [expr {$mode_counter + 1}]
    set slide_$slide_num [$slides Add $slide_num 12]; #add one more slide into the presentation

    set slide_$slide_num\_shapes [[set slide_$slide_num] Shapes]

    set slide_$slide_num\_video_1 [[set slide_$slide_num\_shapes] AddMediaObject2 [file nativename "$job_folder/Report/Mode_$mode_counter\_Iso_Front.avi"] -1 -1 20 100 650 300]

    set slide_$slide_num\_video_2 [[set slide_$slide_num\_shapes] AddMediaObject2 [file nativename "$job_folder/Modal_Analysis/Report/Mode_$mode_counter\_Iso_Back.avi"] -1 -1 500 100 650 300]


    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_shapes"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_video_1"
    lappend object_list "slide_$slide_num\_video_2"

    incr mode_counter 1
}


$active_presentation Save 

foreach object $object_list {
    puts $object
    [set $object] -destroy
}

$slides -destroy
$active_presentation -destroy 

$presents -destroy

$ppt Quit
$ppt -destroy
```

Comment: IIRC, you have to be more careful about freeing every COM object claimed throughout your script, i.e.: `$presents -destroy`, `$active_presentation -destroy`. Your cleanup list `object_list` is not complete. See related questions e.g. on [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776360/tcl-twapi-and-excel-excel-exe-still-running-in-the-background).

Comment: I have tried to ensure that all the created objects are closed. Still don't know what I am missing.

Comment: How did you "ensure" this exactly? I don't see a required `$presents -destroy`, for instance. You need to be more careful.

Comment: Yes, your observation is spot-on. Later, I added $presents -destroy. Still didn't work.

Comment: I have no means to test your script ... not only because it is specific to a setup not shared with us (a spreadsheet of yours), but also because I don't have a TWAPI/ windows setup at hand, I am afraid. Maybe reach out to comp.lang.tcl or attend the Tcl'ers chat?

Comment: The issue was with `$presents Open "$job_folder/Report/Report.pptx";` . It was creating an orphan object that was not bieng destroyed.